# How to convert multi line string values into single line

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I am getting string like this :

```
149
23
45
90
123
29
120
```

I want to convert it like this

```
149, 23,45,90.123,29,120
```

How can I do this, I tried replaceall() method but still getting in different line

```
String atest,btest;
atest = myList2.get(0);

String field = atest.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String field = atest.replaceAll("\\s+", ", ");
```

Comment: nope its not working, its showing blank values

Answer (score -1):

If your incoming string is a multiline string

```
String atest = "149\n" +
            "23\n" +
            "45\n" +
            "90\n" +
            "123\n" +
            "29\n" +
            "120";
    atest = atest.replaceAll("\n",",");
    System.out.println(atest);
```

Comment: i tried it but i am already getting string from a array, i am getting 1st values of array and i want to put it into a single line string

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to achieve. String join will have all the values  with comma separated

Comment: i tried your method its working fine, but in my code, I am getting the atest string from array, and now I want to put it in single line, i have updated the code do check it